# Map angular formarray with model

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form and I need to map the model to form array declaration.

```
  formGroup: FormGroup;
    builder: FormBuilder

    
    data :{
        lineItems : [
          {
            qty: null,
            item: null
          }
        ]
    }
    
    this.formGroup = this.builder.group({
        lineItems: this.builder.array([
            {
            item: [this.lineItems.item, Validators.required],
            }
        ])
    });
```

> I have doubts about this "item: [this.data.lineItems.item,
> Validators.required]"
> domain.lineItems is an array and how can I map it with each formbuilder array.

```
    <div formArrayName="classmates">
        <div *ngFor="let item of lineItems; trackBy: trackId; let i = index;">
            <input
                    type="number"
                    class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't get what is your question. Do you have an error with the code you have, are searching for something better, etc..? Please provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you searching for is:

```
this.formGroup = this.builder.group({
    lineItems: this.builder.array(
        this.data.lineItems.map(line => {
            return this.builder.group({item: [line.item, Validators.required]}
        })
    )
});
```

In that way, you have a formGroup inside of formArray